# Recovering Database after deleting .ldf file

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-recovery

I have deleted the .ldf file. But after that I am unable to recover database.
I have tried to detach and attach database but it is throwing exception.

“The database [dbName] is not accessible. (ObjectExplorer)”

I  have also tried to create a new .ldf file with 0 byte size but database recovery fails.
There is no backup file for database.

I have gone through a post 
[The database [dbName] is not accessible. (ObjectExplorer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123917/the-database-dbname-is-not-accessible-objectexplorer)
But this is related to permission where as my issue is related to deletion of .ldf file.

I do not need log file. **I just want to recover my data**. Transaction log is not important for me.

When I deleted .ldf file SQL server was running. I didn't stopped it at that time.Later I had restarted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose if your database name is xyz, then run following command:

```
ALTER DATABASE xyz REBUILD LOG ON ( NAME = xyz_log, FILENAME ='c:\.....\xyz_log.ldf');
DBCC CHECKDB (xyz);
ALTER DATABASE xyz SET SINGLE_USER;
DBCC CHECKDB (xyz, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS);
ALTER DATABASE xyz SET MULTI_USER;
```

**You may lose some data. This command doesn’t guaranteed full recovery.**